# Laravel stuck with eloquent issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I've been stuck with this eloquent relationship for a while. 
(I'm using laravel 5.2)

A user can have multiple certificates which individually have an aircrafttype. However, it is possible to have a "blank" certificate that doesn't have an aircrafttype.

My goals is to call $user->certificates, and retreive all the certificates of the user with the according aircrafttypes.

I have the following models.

```
    User
    id
    ...


    Aircrafttype
    id
    name 


    Certificate
    id 
    name


    CertificateUser 
    id
    certificate_id
    aircrafttype_id
    user_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a relationship between your `User` model and your `CertificateUser` model.

By the sounds of it, a user can have many certificates - so you would want to use the [`hasMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship. Because you have a column called `user_id` in the `CertificatUser` table, you can simply set up the relationship like this (inside your `User` model:

```
public function certificates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CertificateUser');
    }
```

You can now access this through the `$user` object with `$user->certificates;`

Comment: No worries. You can also add the inverse relationship belongsTo CertificateUser if you like.